# Pushing self.view to navigation controller by allocing, but when coming back same data is shown

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am pushing `self view` to `self.navigationcontroller` by allocating. I have a `tableView` on that view so I am changing the content of `tableview`. But when I am pressing back button (that is automatically created), I am not able to show `previous content`. Its showing updated content.

Please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean "Its showing updated content"? Does it go back to the previous view but the data there has changed? Why is that wrong?

Comment: The question would be understandable more easily if you added some code.

Answer (score 0):

You set code in viewWillAppear method

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {

     //code set here
   }
```

Comment: I am trying to change my variable in viewwillappear or in viewdidappear but its not changing.

Comment: you call tableview reload in this method

Comment: Definitely right.. the content must be updated when you go back. Because when you get pop to previous view the table get reloaded and also the data containing array will get updated with the latest content. So that you are getting the latest content rather than old. If you just want to show the previous content, Just save the previous content while going to next view in "viewWillDisappear" method. And when you get backed to that view just check for pop condition and load the previous content.

Comment: Problem is that, I am not able to find pop. Is there any way to add function for popping a view.

Answer (score 0):

If you fill the `tableView's` data in `viewWillAppear`: or `viewDidAppear`:, it will reload even if you only press the back button of your top `viewController`. If you do not want to have your content changed, you are supposed to use `initWithNibName`: or `viewDidLoad`: methoads. They are called only at creation time of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments on @Kirti's post, You can check if your `viewcontroller` is being popped by following method, and take some necessary actions for you controller holding table.

```cs
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
if(![self.navigationController.viewControllers containsObject:self])
    {
         YourControllerWithTable *instance = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count - 1];
         instance.loadOldContent = YES;
    }
}
```

In `viewWillAppear:` of `YourControllerWithTable`, you can check:

```cs
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(loadOldContent)
    {
    //Do your work here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't push UIView instances onto a UINavigationController instance, only instances of UIViewController.